# akka actor testing using play

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I want to test my akka actor.
Is it possible to test every case of receive function?

```
def receive = {

  case msg: String =>
    println("SUCCESS" + msg)

  case user: VerifyIfUserExistActor =>
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(30 seconds)
    val future = platActor ? user
    val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[Users]
    sender ! result

  case ottDetails: OttDetails =>
    println("SUCCESS" + ottDetails)

}
```

Comment: Please read the akka documentation on how to test actors and ask questions if you face a specific problem. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/testing.html

Comment: Also, don't use Await unless you _must_. See pipeTo for your use case

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to test if you are sending a successful message and just want to see that your actor system works. You can use

```
case _ => println("sending message success")
```

Comment: println isn't a very good test framework.  You should look at things like specs2, mockito, TestKit, etc.